# What does the meaning of "five hours start" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sentence:

> That's strange. He was booked for two days then just after 11:00, he
>   suddenly asks for his bill and leaves. He's got **five hours start**. Put out an alert for the car.

Context: police came to the place, but somehow suspect escapes from the place.
So above words were spoken by commissioner to his partner.

Comment: Before checking Google Books I would have expected *He's got **a five-hour** start.* to be far more common than your "article-less" version, but apparently both occur about equally (not sure if there might be a US/UK usage split though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here **start** most probably refers to **head start**.

The meaning of **head start** in [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/head%20start) states

> an advantage granted or achieved at the beginning of a race, a chase, or a competition

In your sentence, as the person escaped 5 hours before the police, he is 5 hours ahead of the police if they begin to chase him. In other words, he has an advantage of 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the suspect is five hours ahead of the police. When police officers arrived at the place, the subject had already escaped five hours before.